# Group theory: prove that there is an element $s \in S$ such that $f(s) = s$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, prime-numbers, permutations, finite-groups

Let $S$ be a finite set with $n$ elements and let $f \in A(S)$ the set of all bijective functions onto $S$ (this is a group with the composition). Suppose that the order of $f$ is $p$, with $p$ prime, and $p$ does not divide $n$. Prove that there is an element $s \in S$ such that $f(s)=s$.

So, the things I know is that $p$ is the least positive integer such that $f^p(s) = id(s) = s$ for all $s$; $n = qp+r$ for some $q,r$ with $0\leq r<p$. I also established that $s^n = e$ for all $s$ where $e$ is the identity of $S$, but then I realized that $S$ is not necessarily a group.

My first approach was to compute $f^r(s) = f^{n-qp}(s) = f^n \circ((f^p)^{-1})^q(s) = f^n(s)$ since $f^p$ is the identity and so is the inverse, and so is after take $q$ compositions. What I'd like is to find that $f^r(s) = id(s)$ and since $p$ is the order of $f$, necessarily $r=0$ but then $p$ divides $n$ and derive a contradiction.

Then I though about the set $H = \{s \in S:f(s)=s\}$ and show that is not empty, but didn't help. I couldn't came up with the assumtion that $f(s) \neq s$ for all $s$ because I didn't know how to use it.

Now, since $f:S \rightarrow S$ is bijective and $S$ is finite, $f$ is just a permutation, so the cardinality of $A(S)$ is $n!$, and $p$ divides $n!$ but doesn't divide $n$, so $p$ has to divide some number from $1,2,3,\dots,n-1$. But didn't help either.

Any hint, please. Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the [orbit stabilizer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem)?

Comment: Look at the cycle structure of the permutation.  Each cycle must be either a fixed point or of length $p$.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I am not

Comment: @lulu what do you mean by cycle structure?

Comment: A permutation breaks the $n$ numbers up into cycles.  Taking $n=5$, if $1\mapsto 3\mapsto 5 \mapsto 1$ then $(1, 3,5)$ is a cycle.  That permutation could then switch $2,4$ or it could leave both of them fixed.

Comment: [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationCycle.html) is a reference.

Answer (score 2):

Every element of $S$ has order either $1$ or $p$ under $f.$ If every element has order $p,$ you can partition $S$ into disjoint $p$-cycles, proving that $p|n,$ contradiction. So some element has order $1.$

Comment: what do you mean by "order under $f$"?

Comment: @Ejrionm Smallest k such that $f^{k}(a)=a.$